# Beacon Spoofing

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Suppose I have three smartphones that sends a beacon with UUID: X.
Two of them have the App called True App:
The first has major:1, minor:1
The second has major:1, minor:2

The third smartphone has the App called Beacon Simulator that clone the beacon of the others two ones.

The first two should be recognise that the third is spoofing beacon.

Which is the best approach to solve this issue for both Android and iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three common approaches to avoiding beacon spoofing:

1. **Use a secondary transmitted identifier**

   You can use a secondary known identifier that is harder to copy (e.g. the bluetooth MAC address) to try and verify that the beacon identifier comes from the expected source.  **This technique rarely works well**, however, because a determined hacker can also spoof the MAC address (or any other transmitted field) with the proper equipment.  Using this approach with MAC address is also very limited on mobile devices -- iOS devices cannot read a beacon's MAC address at all, and both Android and iOS transmitters randomize their BLE transmitters periodically.
2. **Rotating identifier hashes**

   There are a number of beacon systems that attempt to avoid spoofing by using a dedicated beacon format that uses a rotating identifier based on a secure cryptographic hashing algorithm.  Two examples of this are Gimbal (proprietary) and Eddystone-EID (open source, but effectively run by Google).  In each case, you must make a call to a server to "resolve" the rotating hash you receive from the beacon transmission and effectively convert it to a static identifier your app can use.
   **This approach is quite secure for many use cases, but there are  major shortcomings**: (a) The systems are complex and difficult to set up.  (b) Network connectivity is required to resolve the identifier.  If you lose connectivity or the network is slow, your app won't work.  (c) The approach locks you in to specific vendors (Gimbal or Google). (d) The system can still be defeated by recording a beacon transmission in one location and rebroadcasting it in a second location.
3. **Use secondary factors to validate the beacon detection**

   One example of a secondary factor is verifying the known location of each beacon.  If you know the latitude and longitude of each beacon, when you see the beacon, compare the measured latitude and longitude to see if it is reasonably close.  This will prevent spoofing except in close proximity.  Another example might be time.  If you know two different beacons will be placed over one mile apart, but your phone detects both of them within a few seconds, then you can be reasonably sure that one of the two detections was spoofed and respond appropriately.  There are many, many other possibilities that are use-case specific.  **This approach often provides a good tradeoff between basic security and ease of implementation**, provided that your use case allows it and your security requirements are not extreme.